# autofac: component registration being ignored

Tags: c#, autofac

The following class takes a primitive on the constructor, so I need to tell AutoFac how to generate said value using a delegate:

```
public class BackgroundTaskScheduler : IStartable
{
    private readonly IJobRunner _jobRunner;
    private int _triggerMilliseconds;


    public BackgroundTaskScheduler(IJobRunner jobRunner, int triggerMilliseconds)
    {
        _jobRunner = jobRunner;
        _triggerTimespan = triggerMilliseconds;
    }
}


public static class AutoFac
{
    public static void Configure()
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

        var triggerInterval =
                int.Parse(
                    ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TaskScheduleTriggerMilliseconds"]);

        builder.Register(
            c => new BackgroundTaskScheduler(c.Resolve<IJobRunner>(), triggerInterval)).AsImplementedInterfaces().SingleInstance();

        builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof (RegistrationController).Assembly)
            .AsImplementedInterfaces()
            .AsSelf();

        IContainer container = builder.Build();

    }
}
```

However, Autofac appears to ignore my registration as evidenced by the exception it throws when resolving an instance of `BackgroundTaskScheduler`:

**None of the constructors found with 'Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.DefaultConstructorFinder' on type 'Delen.Server.Tasks.BackgroundTaskScheduler' can be invoked with the available services and parameters:
Cannot resolve parameter 'System.Int32 triggerMilliseconds' of constructor 'Void .ctor(Delen.Server.Tasks.IJobRunner, System.Int32)'.**

I've successfully used the `IContainerBuilder.Register` method before in exactly such a scenario but I've no clue why it's not working this go around.

**Update 1**

Changing the order of the registrations did not make a difference.

**Update 2**

Here's an alternative way to achieve the same result as the accepted Answer:

```
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(IJobRunner).Assembly)
    .Except<BackgroundTaskScheduler>()
    .AsImplementedInterfaces()
    .AsSelf()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of the registrations **does** mater beside that using the assembly scanning features can be dangerous if you also want to register types by hand because you could end up interfering registrations.

In your case you are registering your `BackgroundTaskScheduler` **twice**

- once with the correct parameters when calling `builder.Register`
- the second type when calling `builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes` this time without the required `triggerInterval` parameter.

So you've ended up two registrations where one of them is not correct so when calling `builder.Build` you get the exception.

To fix it you need to exclude all the hand registered types in the `RegisterAssemblyTypes` call:

```
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(AutofacRegistrationOrderTest).Assembly)
    .Where(t => t != typeof(BackgroundTaskScheduler))
    .AsImplementedInterfaces()
    .AsSelf();

builder.Register(
    c => new BackgroundTaskScheduler(c.Resolve<IJobRunner>(), triggerInterval))
    .AsImplementedInterfaces()
    .SingleInstance();
```

Comment: @MitchA in general the order does matter and in this case you probably have a different problem, I've update my answer.